# Double request in web api service

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a really weird problem with a web api service I developed. The service is called through javascript in client-side.
The service can sometime takes a lot of time to process the request and in this cases, after 30 seconds (always 30 seconds), we detect a new request on the web service (on the IIS logs). But using Chrome's Network logger, we can't see any request being send again by the browser...
Looking at the code there is also nothing that makes a retry after 30 seconds.

Any idea what might be happening? Can it be a browser issue? A web balancer issue? Javascript issue? Server configuration issue?

thanks a lot in advance,
Pedro

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know a specific solution to your problem, I suggest using a Web Proxy such as Charles to detect requests made by the browser.  I have discovered that some browsers hide how many requests are actually made.  For example, Safari makes 2 requests when using the  tag, while nothing in their network inspector / logs indicate multiple requests.  Only when using a web proxy did I realize this.  Hopefully, if you haven't already tried this, it will help you discover a solution.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

seems like there was some kind of wrong configuration on the proxy servers on the web hosting that was creating duplicate calls after 30 seconds with no response. Sorry I can't give you any technical detail about that but they didn't gave me. Scary though...

Answer (score 0):

Multiple entities in the chain between the browser and your service, including proxy servers/load balancers, may be setup to retry requests if they don't hear a response after a certain period of time.

Unfortunately I don't believe there is a general answer how to address this as this is tool specific.